# Setting a breakpoint via code in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, breakpoints

Is there any statement in Actionscript 3 which acts as a breakpoint when executed? That is, something like [JavaScript's "debugger" statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger).

I need it when developing AS3 applications without an IDE. Setting the breakpoint manually in fdb is rather tedious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use enterDebugger function.

```
import flash.debugger.enterDebugger;

// code ...
enterDebugger()
// code ...
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to put a breakpoint _inside_ the enterDebugger function, so you have to use "step" in fdb to reach the code you want to debug.